# Windows 10 showing "ghost" Drive Letters

Tags: windows-10, disk-management

Yesterday I had to reset (PSU switch off-wait-on) my Computer, when i started it again it ran a disk check and installed the cumulative update released a few days ago.

Now its showing two drive letters for every disk, The "normal" ones for the Volumes `C`, `D` and `T` and the strange ones, `E`,`G`,`I`-`L`. As you can see on the Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

four of them are in a Software-RAID-0, their Volume has the letter `D`, but every single disk now has an "own" letter, The System Disk even has three Letters.

I already:

- rebooted
- plugged it out, waited 5 minutes and plugged it back in
- deleted the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\DelegateFolders\{F5FB2C77-0E2F-4A16-A381-3E560C68BC83}` Key

but nothing worked.

My Guess is that some weird bug makes windows assign Letters to hidden partitions, cause the System Disk has three letters; `C`=System, `E`=maybe msftres, `F`=EFI, the other ones got two.
I'm running Windows 10 Enterprise x64.

Any Idea what I could do? (except for re-install Windows or restoring a Backup)

Comment: You want to post an *answer*, not edit the question. In addition, looks like you have two accounts - you should use the contact us link to request a merger,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I formatted my System Disk and reinstalled Windows, a few hours later the "ghostletters" (My guess was right, they were assigned to the efi boot and msftres partitions) were back.

I don't know why this happens yet, but I've found a Solution: ext2fsd, an ext2/3/4 file system driver for Windows with a built-in drive letter manager. A few clicks later, everything was fine again, even after a reboot.